# Unsort NSTableView column

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

In my NSTableView I can click to sort Ascending and click to sort Descending, but after I do this, how can I restore the original unsorted order?

Comment: you can't - it is a random order... but maybe reloading the data and deleting sort descriptors beforehand might help

Comment: my middle school PE teacher always said "can't means won't and won't means push-ups"

Comment: sorry, my middle school teacher spoke german with me and english was introduced when i was 14 ;)